# Failed: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined for a login test

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have written the following tests:

```
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { GlobalDataService } from '../services/global-data.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';


describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule,
         OverlayModule, MatDialogModule ],
      providers: [ GlobalDataService, DatePipe, AuthenticationService ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should set instance correctly', () => {
    expect(component).not.toBeNull();
   });

  it('should call auth login method', waitForAsync(() => {
    let loginElement: DebugElement;
    const debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    const authenticationService = debugElement.injector.get(AuthenticationService);
    const loginSpy = spyOn(authenticationService, 'login').and.callThrough();
    loginElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('form'));
    // to set values
    component.loginForm.controls.username.setValue('test@test.com');
    component.loginForm.controls.password.setValue('testpassword');
    loginElement.triggerEventHandler('ngSubmit', null);
    expect(loginSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // check that service is called once
    // ^ this fails without correct login!
   }));

  it('should render "Login" at the top of the login page', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h5').textContent).toContain('Login');
  });
});
```

My Login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';
import { GlobalDataService } from '../services/global-data.service';

/* tslint:disable variable-name */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  returnUrl: string;
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  error = '';
  loading = false;
  public errorMsg = 'Please login to continue';
  public redirected: boolean;
  public utm_source: string;

  constructor(private router: Router, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public DataService: GlobalDataService,
              public authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
      this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      const param = params.utm_source;

      if ([ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].includes(param)) {
        this.redirected = true;
        this.utm_source = param;
      } else {
        this.redirected = false;
      }
  });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]]
  });
  }

// convenience getter for easy access to form fields
get f() { return this.loginForm.controls; }

  onSubmit(loginsubmit) {
    this.submitted = true;
    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
        return console.log('LoginForm Invalid');
    }
    this.loading = true;

    this.authenticationService.login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value)
        .pipe()
        .subscribe(
            data => {
              // it was this.returnUrl instead of avior/dashboard
                if (this.redirected) {
                  this.router.navigate([this.utm_source]);
                } else {
                  this.router.navigate(['landing-page']);
                }
            },
            error => {
                console.log('Login->authservice->err: ', error);
                this.error = error;
                this.loading = false;
            });
}
}
```

The error I get happens on the `should call auth login method` test with the following error:

```
Failed: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined
```

So it appears that the LoginForm form is somewhy and somehow undefined. Any clue why that might be? The definition of the form field appears to be fine, I have honestly no clue what's wrong. The most weird part is that it used to work and now it doesn't after migrating the code. I tried mendling with the code with no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In you test setup you are trying to set a value on a control that doesn't exist in your form.

`component.loginForm.controls.username.setValue('test@test.com'); // username doesn't exisit`

the property is called email. try to change the line to:

`component.loginForm.controls.email.setValue('test@test.com');`

Answer (score 0):

##### I had similar error:

**Ensure to to initialize the form creation and patch under constructor and ngOnInit respectively i.e**

```
 // creation goes in constructor
  dataFormGroup:FormGroup
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.dataFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
     ......
     ..........
   })

// patch/setvalue goes under ngOnInit
ngOnInit() {
  let urlData = history.state
  this.mode = urlData.mode
  this.update_data = urlData.user
  if (this.mode == "edit") {
    this.dataFormGroup.patchValue({
      first_name: this.update_data.first_name,
      last_name: this.update_data.last_name,
      ...
      .....
    });
  }
}
```